# Symfony forms: avoid having submit button

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I am using Symfony framework and I want to create a form without the submit button.

I explain myself better: I have a simple form, like the following one:

```
      $form = $this->createFormBuilder($defaultData);
      $form->add($fieldname, 'choice', array(
          'choices' => array( 
              '3' => 'label_3', 
              '2' => 'label_2', 
              '1' => 'label_1', 
              '0' => 'label_0', 
              ), 
          'expanded'    => false, 
          'label'       => 'choice',
          ));
      $form->add('send', 'submit', array(
          'label'       => 'send'
          ));
```

Is there a way to avoid having a "submit" button?
The resulting behavior I want to enforce is: 
- The User selects the desired choice
- On click, data is immediately submitted and handled by the controller

I searched in the Symfony manual, but I failed finding something that could fit.
Can anyone help me? (Is i even possible to have such a behavior?)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you don't want the submit button, why did you add it in your code?

Comment: I just displayed what I am using **now**. It is a stable working solution. As an improvement, I wanted the same functionality **without** the submit button.

Comment: I can conclude from answer what were you looking for to achieve BUT, beware, absence of submit button violates some major `UX` patterns and your users could easily end up confused/frustrated... think about it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do this via JavaScript:

```
$('#formFieldId').change(function(){
     $(this).closest('form').trigger('submit');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for ".closest" function , didn't know it, should be very useful with multiple form :)

Answer (score 0):

you should try with javascript like this :

```
   jQuery().ready( function() {

        // for example your fieldname id is "field"
        jQuery( "#field").change( function(){

              jQuery('form').submit();

        });
   });
```

you don t have to put you submit button in your form by the way, the standard way is to include the html for the button within the twig file